# chrome options in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework, selenium2library

I am trying to download a file from a link on webpage. However I get annoying warning "This type of file can harm...anyway? Keep, Discard". I tried several options to avoid the warning but still getting it. I am using robot framework however I am using python to create new keyword for me.

```
@keyword('open "${url}" in chrome browser')
    def open_chrome_browser(self, url):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
        options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
        options.add_argument("--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist")
        options.add_argument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection")
        prefs = {'safebrowsing.enabled': 'true'}
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        self.open_browser(url, 'chrome',alias=None, remote_url=False, desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities(), ff_profile_dir=None)
```

Can someone please suggest a way to disable the download warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer with some research. For some reason (may be a bug) open_browser does not set capabilities for chrome. 
So, the alternative is to use 'create_webdriver'. Worked with following code:

```
@keyword('open "${url}" in chrome browser')
def open_chrome_browser(self, url):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
    options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
    options.add_argument("--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist")
    options.add_argument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection")
    prefs = {'safebrowsing.enabled': 'true'}
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    instance = self.create_webdriver('Chrome', desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())
    self.go_to(url)
```

Comment: please share the link where you got  the below values from? am unable to find it.
--start-maximized,--disable-web-security -allow-running-insecure-content") --safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist") --safebrowsing-disable-download-protectio

Answer (score 5):

You need to add all the params in list. Then  pass this list to Dictionary object and pass it to open browser.
Ex.

```
${list} =     Create List    --start-maximized    --disable-web-security
${args} =     Create Dictionary    args=${list}
${desired caps} =     Create Dictionary    platform=${OS}     chromeOptions=${args}
Open Browser    https://www.google.com    remote_url=${grid_url}    browser=${BROWSER}    desired_capabilities=${desired caps}
```

Answer (score 3):

The below would be a simpler solution:

Open Browser    ${URL}  ${BROWSER}      options=add_argument("--disable-notifications")

for multiple option, you can use with ; seperated.

options=add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking"); add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to disable any security features or any other defaults(unless there is ample justification) which comes with the browser "just to solve one problem", it would be better to find the solution by not touching it at all, and

just make use of requests modules in python and use the same as keyword, wherever you would want later on in all of your codebases. The reason for this approach is that it is better to get the job done making use of ubiquitous modules rather than spending time on one module for extensive amounts of time, I use to do that before, better install requests + robotframework-requests library and others to just get the job completed.

Just use the below code to create a keyword out of it and call it wherever you want, instead of going through the hassle of fixing browser behavior.

```
import requests

file_url = "http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"

r = requests.get(file_url, stream=True)

with open("sample.pdf", "wb") as pdf:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):

        # writing one chunk at a time to pdf file
        if chunk:
            pdf.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (must use `SeleniumLibrary 4`). Modify Chrome so it downloads PDFs instead of viewing them:

```
${chrome_options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
${disabled}  Create List  Chrome PDF Viewer  PrintFileServer
${prefs}  Create Dictionary  download.prompt_for_download=${FALSE}  plugins.always_open_pdf_externally=${TRUE}  plugins.plugins_disabled=${disabled}
Call Method  ${chrome_options}  add_experimental_option  prefs  ${prefs}

${desired_caps}=  Create Dictionary  browserName=${browserName}  version=${version}  platform=${platform}  screenResolution=${screenResolution}  record_video=${record_video}  record_network=${record_network}  build=${buildNum}  name=${globalTestName}

Open Browser  url=${LOGINURL}  remote_url=${remote_url}  options=${chrome_options}  desired_capabilities=${desired_caps}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me worked code below:

```
UI Test Case in Chrome
    ${chrome_options} =    Evaluate    selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --start-maximized
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --window-size\=1420,1080
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-extensions
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --no-sandbox
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-dev-shm-usage
    Create WebDriver    Chrome    options=${chrome_options}
    Set Selenium Implicit Wait    15s
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please elaborate on how your answer complements the already-accepted answer.